# Problem with Awodey's Category Theory 8.8 Topoi, an alternative characterization of subobject classifiers.

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

> **Definition 8.16.** Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a category with all finite limits. A subobject classifier in $\mathcal{E}$ consists of an object $\Omega$ together with an arrow $t : 1 \to \Omega$ that is a "universal subobject," in the following sence:
>
> Given any object $E$ and any subobject $U \to E$ (injective, but mse doesn't support tikzcd), there is a unique arrow $u: E \to \Omega$ making the following diagram a pullback:

[image]

> $\cdots$
>
> It is easy to show that a subobject classifier is unique up to isomorphism: the pullback condition is clearly equivalent to requiring the contravariant subobject functor,
> $$\mathrm{Sub}_{\mathcal{E}}(-): \mathcal{E}^{op} \to \mathbb{Sets}$$
> (which acts by pullback) to be representable,
> $$\mathrm{Sub}_{\mathcal{E}}(-) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal{E}}(-, \Omega)$$

It is easy to go left to right, but I'm having trouble going the other way, from the isomorphism of the two functors to the desired UMP.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the usual argument how to recover a universal property from a representable presheaf. Plugging in $\Omega$ into the isomorphism of functors yields a universal subobject $t$ that corresponds to the identity on $\Omega$, and then the desired universality follows immediately since every map into $f\colon E\to\Omega$ is the image of the identity on $\Omega$ along $f^\ast$ and since $f^\ast$ acts on subobjects by means of pullback along $f$.

Edit: To see that the domain  $X$ of $t$ is the terminal object, note that any morphism $f\colon E\to X$ determines a map $tf$ and therefore a subobject of $E$. By construction, $E$ must be a retract of this subobject, which is only possible if the subobject is the maximal one (i.e. the identity on $E$). As the identity on $E$ defines a subobject of $E$ and therefore gives rise to such a map $f$, this shows that there is a unique such map $f$, hence $X$ is terminal.

Comment: How can I know that the domain of t is the terminal object 1, or do I need to?

Comment: @AprilGrimoire Good question. In fact, you can deduce this from the definition of subobject classifier! So if you replace $1$ in the definition tot quoted by some object $X$ (and stipulate that $t$ must be a monomorphism) then you can deduce that $X$ is the terminal object.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: @asdq In your edit: how do you know there is a morphism $E \to X$.

Comment: I didn't follow up to "By construction, E must be a retract of this object". Could you explain it a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: @Mark Kamsma The maximal subobject of $E$ gives rise to such a map.

Comment: @AprilGrimoire Could you be more specific? What part don't you understand?

Comment: @asdq What does "By construction" mean? Does a retract mean an object to which an arrow has a right inversion?

Comment: @asdq I agree, but that bit was missing.

Comment: @AprilGrimoire Yes, it means that the inclusion of the subobject will admit a right inverse, given by the map induced from $f$ and the identity on $E$ using the universal property of pullback squares. This is best seen by drawing the diagram.

Comment: In fact, I've seen some references provisionally call the source of the universal subobject $t$ as $\Omega_0$ before then showing that $\Omega_0$ is a final object so we might as well replace it with $1$.

Comment: @asdq Sorry for bothering, does "the map induced from f" mean tf? Is the two arrows of the pullback t and tf?

Comment: @DanielSchepler Could you provide a reference to it? Thanks!

Comment: I mean the map into the subobject (which is defined as the pullback of $t$ along $tf$) that is induced from the pair $(f, \operatorname{id}_E)$ via the universal property of pullback.

Comment: @MarkKamsma The existence of such f can be found out by checking the corresponding edge in Hom(E, Omega) and taking pullback of t through it.

Comment: @asdq I finally got it! I think this is probably not easy... Is Awodey's book too hard for me?

Comment: @AprilGrimoire As I said: I agree, but that part should be mentioned as well, because it is part of the proof. As for your question if the book is too hard: if you understand all this I think you're doing well. Many of these category-theoretic tricks are hard when you first see them. It is normal to get stuck every now and then, don't let that discourage you!

Comment: @AprilGrimoire One reference which uses the provisional $\Omega_0$ is "Toposes, Triples, and Theories" which is available online.  That's where I first learned the basics of topos theory - although it's possibly somewhat dated (what it calls "triples", the terminology has settled down to "monads", for instance).  As far as I recall, that reference also doesn't treat the internal language of a topos, unfortunately.